# $f$ nonnegative, continuous in $[a,b]$ and such that $\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$ implies $f(x)=0$ in $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

My book proves the following statement: "Let $f$ be nonnegative and continuous in $[a,b]$ and such that
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$$
then $f$ is identically $0$ in $[a,b]$." using an argument by contradiction.

However, I've tried to prove it in a direct way (which takes way more effort, but I would like to know if there is a flaw in my reasoning or not), can someone check if my work is okay please?

My try: by hypothesis $f$ is nonnegative in $[a,b]$: if $f(x)=0$, the theorem is true.

So let's suppose $f(x)>0$: let $x_0 \in [a,b]$, by hypothesis $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, so in particular it is continuous in $x_0$. Since $f$ is positive in this case, I can chooose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}f(x_0)$ in the definition of continuity to get the inequality $\frac{1}{2}f(x_0) \leq f(x) \leq \frac{3}{2}f(x_0)$ if $x_0-\delta_\epsilon < x < x_0+\delta_\epsilon$. Since by hypothesis $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, it is integrable in $[a,b]$ as well, so by monotonicity of integral it is
$$\int_{x_0-\delta_\epsilon}^{x_0+\delta_\epsilon} \frac{1}{2}f(x_0)\,dx \leq \int_{x_0-\delta_\epsilon}^{x_0+\delta_\epsilon} f(x)\,dx \leq \int_{x_0-\delta_\epsilon}^{x_0+\delta_\epsilon} \frac{3}{2} f(x_0)\,dx$$
By hypothesis $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$, so in particular $\int_{x_0-\delta_\epsilon}^{x_0+\delta_\epsilon} f(x)\,dx=0$; hence from the last inequality it follows that $\delta_\epsilon f(x_0) \leq 0 \leq 3\delta_\epsilon f(x_0)$. Since $\delta_\epsilon>0$, This means that $f(x_0)$ is both $\geq0$ and $\leq 0$, the only possibility is that $f(x_0)=0$. Since $x_0 \in[a,b]$ is arbitrary, this holds for all $x\in[a,b]$ and so $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Is this correct? If it is maybe I should've put more attention in the intervals of the kind $[a,x_0+\delta_\epsilon]$ and $[x_0-\delta_\epsilon,b]$ because since $\delta_\epsilon$ if $x_0$ is too much near the boundary I risk to "go out" of $[a,b]$, but I'm not sure if this is a problem or not since if $\delta_\epsilon$ works a lesser $\delta'_\epsilon$ would work too and so I can restrict it as much as I need.

Comment: *“So let's suppose $f(x_0) > 0$”* – isn't that a proof by contradiction?

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks for your comment. I meant that since $f$ is nonnegative by hypothesis it can have only two behaviours: or is $f(x)>0$ or is $f(x)=0$, and since I've already discussed when $f(x)=0$ I've said that to specify that I'm discussing the case when $f(x)>0$. If it wasn't clear, have you some suggestions to make it clearer to the reader?

Comment: To conclude the integral on $[x_0-\delta_\varepsilon,x_0+\delta_\varepsilon]$ is $0$, you need to use Chasles' relation. However, I find this proof a bit complicated. I think it's better to use thestandard proof, which is not a proof by contradiction, as you said, but a proof by contrapositive.

Answer (score 1):

You must pick some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)>0$, you can't just pick $x_0$ completely arbitrarily. It can easily happen that $f$ is only positive on, say, some small interval.

Other than that, yes, once $f(x_0)>0$, there is a nondegenerate interval containing $x_0$ on which $f(x)>f(x_0)/2$, and so the integral on that interval is positive. Meanwhile the integral elsewhere is nonnegative. So you conclude that if $f$ is nonnegative, continuous, and not identically zero, then its integral is nonzero, which is a contrapositive of the desired statement.

I would call this general type of argument either contradiction or contraposition, though, so I'm a bit surprised that you think this is especially direct.

Comment: I haven't specified that $x_0$ is such that $f(x_0)>0$ because I was discussing the case of $f(x)>0$ and so it was implicit that $f(x_0)>0$; if it wasn't clear, have you some advices to make it clearer to the reader?
I didn't think it was a contradiction because I didn't get any, and from my point of view contrapositive is somehow direct :) thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ZaWarudo You are asked to prove that $f$ is zero *everywhere*, so the negation of that for use in proof by contraposition is that it is nonzero *somewhere*, not that it is nonzero *everywhere*. That is, assuming $f(x)>0$ everywhere and concluding $\int_a^b f(x) dx > 0$ *does not* furnish the desired statement; you are assuming more than you are allowed to assume. (This is not just a matter of style, it is actually important.) As for my last remark, I just don't see how much less direct your book's proof could really be than this one.

Answer (score 1):

The major points here are the right idea but this isn't necessarily a "direct proof" (if by direct you mean showing $p$ implies $q$) since you are saying that $f(x) > 0$ cannot happen by some contradiction.
One thing to note is that not every proof has a "direct way" to prove it as even some reasoning used in the proof could actually by due to contradiction or contrapositive

For example, let's consider another possible argument which is simply a modification of what you wrote here.
Say you take arbitrary $x_0 \in [a,b]$ and then show (using similar reasoning here) that for all $\epsilon > 0$, we have $f(x_0) < \epsilon$.
Then you would conclude that since $f(x_0) \geq 0$ that $f(x_0) = 0$.
However, the very fact that given a number $r \geq 0$, if $r \leq \epsilon$ for all positive $\epsilon$, then $r =0$ is proven necessarily with contradiction, so it can't always be avoided. This is part of the nature of real analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is non-negative on $[a,b]$ then that suggests that $f(x)\ge0$ on $[a,b]$ and so:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\ge0$$
for a function to be non-zero and the integral be zero over $[a,b]$ there must be a point of discontinuity $c\in(a,b)$ such that:
$$\int_a^cf(x)dx=-\int_c^bf(x)dx$$
but this is a contradiction because this function is discontinuous and would have to be negative at some point, and so the only solution is:
$$iff\,\,\,\int_a^bf(x)dx=0,f(x)\ge0\Rightarrow f(x)=0$$